# Randomised Path from A to B for cursor movement simulation

Tags: javascript, random, path

I'm trying to simulate the movement of the mousecursor, by creating a path from point A to B that has random variation. The algorithm I'm using at the moment is very basic, and is limited in that  it's only really good for creating a path where X and Y distance from the start are the same, forming a square:

[image: Current algorithm]

The code looks something like this:

```
   function calcualtePath(from, to)
   {
      var pathNodes = [];
      while (from.x != to.x || from.y != to.y)
      {
         var newTransition = {x: from.x, y: from.y};

         if (Rand(1, 3) != 1 && newTransition.x > to.x)       newTransition.x--;
         else if (Rand(1, 3) != 1 && newTransition.x < to.x)  newTransition.x++;
         if (Rand(1, 3) != 1 && newTransition.y > to.y)       newTransition.y--;
         else if (Rand(1, 3) != 1 && newTransition.y < to.y)  newTransition.y++;

         pathNodes.push(newTransition);
         from = newTransition;
      }
      return pathNodes;
   }
```

I'd like some assistance in creating is a relatively fast algorithm that creates a randomised path between point A and B, that has a more curve like path and isn't limited like the one above. Ideally something a bit like this, with a pronounced curve:

[image: Ideal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about using bezier curves? Check out this link that explains them.

http://blog.demofox.org/2014/03/04/bezier-curves/

You'll have to come up with the intermediary control point(s) but it should be pretty simple to do.

Hermite interpolation might be more what you are after, but that is mathematically equivelant, just in a different form.

If you want it to look imperfect, you could add some jitter on top of the curve path (:

Comment: I reckon that ought to do the trick. Now, to figure out how to generate a list of coords that follow such a curve. Thank you for the tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: If you have 3 points (the two end points, plus a control point in the middle that you can calculate based on whatever rules give you the best results), the equation for a quadratic bezier curve is this:

A*(1-t)^2 + B*2t(1-t) + C*t^2

Where A and C are the endpoints and B is the control point i mentioned.  You evaluate that function separately on each axis, so in 2d it would be this:  
`P.x = A.x*(1-t)^2 + B.x*2t(1-t) + C.x*t^2  
P.y = A.y*(1-t)^2 + B.y*2t(1-t) + C.y*t^2`  
t is a value between 0 and 1 that you evaluate to get the middle points.  The more values of t, the smoother the curve.

Comment: Also, there's an interactive demo on my site where you can play with it to get a feel for how it works. http://demofox.org/bezquad.html

Comment: Alan, I think your bias/gain formula is even better. Very nice website :)

Comment: Thanks! (: lots of diff ways to do it. You could probably make bias and gain work, but the hard part with those is that you can't move the end points very easily

Comment: I've gone with your quadratic bezier curve formula, but the issue I now have is it's not a clean line of pixels always. I don't know how many pixels I need for any given curve to ensure a clean unbroken line.

Comment: ohh... yeah, that's true.  If you saw my web based curve demo I linked, where you can drag the control points around, what i do is generate a fixed number of curve points (100 in my case... could probably get by with less though), and i draw a straight line between each curve point.  That ends up working pretty well, if you have the ability to draw a straight line.

Comment: I can draw a straight line, but that sounds like it would get computationally expensive to do it so often. I'll give it a shot and see what I can do. Thank you :)

Comment: It might not be as bad as you think.  I'd give it a shot and see.  If it does turn out to be too perf intensive for you though, you might try bresenham's quadratic bezier drawing algorithm.  You can find it (and other bresenham algorithms) here:

http://members.chello.at/easyfilter/bresenham.html


Bresenham is the go to algorithm for drawing lines and circles (and other things) when you only have per pixel drawing available.  It's very efficient. Also it's based on equations where all numbers involved are integers, so it is always exactly precise in pixels, no rounding errors.

Comment: I also just noticed your question is tagged as javascript!  Check this out for info on how to draw a quadratic curve using javascript's built in functions:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_quadraticcurveto.asp

And here's a cubic curve (4 control points):
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp

Comment: I don't think I can use canvas, because I need to generate a list of coordinates between two points that form a curve, and I'm triggering events at each coordinate. Drawing is for testing.